# "conversion from type 'datarowview' to type 'string' is not valid "on Checklistbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checklistbox

I have problem about my checklistbox .It have name of subject in checklistbox and I want to pop up message subject what user is checked

```
For Each Item As String In CheckedListBox_subject.CheckedItems
            MsgBox(Item)
Next
```

and i got ERROR

```
"conversion from type 'datarowview' to type 'string' is not valid"
```

at `CheckedListBox_subject.CheckedItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use the correct type:

```
For Each Item As DataRowView In CheckedListBox_subject.CheckedItems
     Dim text As String = Item(0).ToString() ' or any other column, you can also use the string overload
     MsgBox(text)
Next
```

Comment: CheckedItems is of  type DataRowView.  don't we  need casting here?

Answer (score 0):

The following shows when the DataSource is a DataTable

For more see my [code article](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CheckListBox-LoadingRetriev-70b0c202) at Microsoft.

```
Public Class Form1
    ''' <summary>
    ''' clbCheckedListBox is our CheckedListBox
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim dt As New DataTable With {.TableName = "MyTable"}

        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Identifier",
                                            .DataType = GetType(Int32),
                                            .AutoIncrement = True,
                                            .AutoIncrementStep = 100,
                                            .AutoIncrementSeed = 100})

        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "ItemName",
                                            .DataType = GetType(String)})

        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "ExtraData",
                                            .DataType = GetType(String)})


        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, "One", "Extra 1"})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, "Two", "Extra 2"})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, "Three", "Extra 3"})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, "Four", "Extra 4"})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, "Five", "Extra 5"})

        clbCheckedListBox.DataSource = dt
        clbCheckedListBox.DisplayMember = "ItemName"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Checked As CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection =
            clbCheckedListBox.CheckedItems

        If Checked.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Conventional  method to react
        For Each drv As DataRowView In Checked

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",
                              drv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Identifier"),
                              drv.Row.Field(Of String)("ItemName"),
                              drv.Row.Field(Of String)("ExtraData")
                              )

        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```